# Customize sharepoint file list

Tags: css, branding

I am trying to create four rectangular divs so that when I click on a div a list with files appears. Just like a simple file list element but with a custumized interface (instead of the folders I want a rectangular div for each folder with some hover effect).

I know how to create the divs and the hover effects (pure .css or some js script included in the layout's page html), but I have no idea how to implement the rest (linking them to the files so that when I click one div it takes me to the list of files).

Should I try to customize a simple file list or there is another way to achieve this?

Please help me.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest investigating JSLink to see if that will do what you want. You can take a standard list table and using JSLink provide custom Client Side rendering.

My suggested resource list includes:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn745867.aspx

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a

http://www.wonderlaura.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=daba3a3b%2Dc338%2D41d8%2Dbf52%2Dcd897d000cf3&ID=228&Web=dbb90e85%2Db54c%2D49f4%2D8e97%2D6d8258116ca0